# Fedora 21 - Show and hide Terminal

Tags: fedora

Is it possible to configure the given terminal application in Fedora 21, so you can show and hide it with shortcuts? It would be great if the terminal would appear from above the screen.

**Note**: I know there are some third application who can deal with it like `Yakuake` or `Tilda`, but I really like the current Terminal theme even if Linus think it's to "Emo" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the default terminal application, gnome-terminal, does not have this feature.

However, Fedora provides many other terminal applications, including the ones you mention. These are generally configurable to some degree, so you may get them to a "theme" you like.

Alternately, you could try [the *drop down terminal* gnome shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/442/drop-down-terminal/), which, as the name implies, also provides this functionality.